# converting character to HMS - big data

Tags: r

I have a huge DF with 30mil rows.
I'm importing it fast with the function

```
fread("")
```

Which made everything faster but **imports HMS column as character**

here is en example DF

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
timeWork <- c("00:00:00.239", "00:01:01.029", "00:00:01")
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, timeWork)
```

I'm able to transform it back to HMS using

```
employ.data$timeWork <- hms::as_hms(employ.data$timeWork)
```

but it takes a few minutes because of the data size.

I've heard about the function `fastPOSIXct` but I could not understand how to use it.
whe I try:

```
employ.data$timeWork <- fasttime::fastPOSIXct(employ.data$timeWork)
```

It turns all my data to NA.

Is there any faster way?
Thanks a lot

Comment: POSIXct is a datetime class. You don't have dates, only times, so POSIXct is not a good option.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clerification

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, while data.table-1.14.0 added speed improvements when reading in full datetime data, [data.table#4841](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4841) suggests it is not implemented for `ITime` objects.

As an alternative, the `vroom` package provides a time parser as a column-type. While `vroom` alleges good speed in general, I have not benchmarked it against really large files.

```r
txt <- '"employee","timeWork"
"John Doe","00:00:00.239"
"Peter Gynn","00:01:01.029"
"Jolie Hope","00:00:01"'

library(vroom)

types <- list(
  employee = col_character(),
  timeWork = col_time(format = "%H:%M:%OS")
)
out <- vroom(txt, delim = ",", col_types = types)

out
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   employee   timeWork   
#   <chr>      <drtn>     
# 1 John Doe    0.239 secs
# 2 Peter Gynn 61.029 secs
# 3 Jolie Hope  1.000 secs

str(out, give.attr = FALSE)
# spec_tbl_df [3 x 2] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ employee: chr [1:3] "John Doe" "Peter Gynn" "Jolie Hope"
#  $ timeWork: 'hms' num [1:3] 0.239 61.029 1
```

Note that the default `format=` is `"%H:%M:%S"` which, in this example, will not parse the decimal seconds correctly, so `"%OS"` is required (otherwise `timeWork[1]` is `0`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to use col_time when importing a .csv file (inside fread() function) or how to use it in order to manipulate an existing column after importing the data. Should I specify the time of each column in a list first? I have 100 of columns.

Comment: My code specifically shows that. If you don't know all of the column names, just include the one you *do* know, `timeWork` in your example. My `types` list is precisely what you need to make. Said differently, given the sample data you gave, if you replace my `txt` with your filename, *this should work*.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this:
`types <- list(Video.Time = col_time(format = "%H:%M:%OS"))`
`myFile <- fread("workingFile.csv", colClasses = types)`
but I get an error: 
Warning messages:
**1: In fread("workingFile.csv", colClasses = types) : NAs introduced by coercion**
**2: In fread("workingFile.csv", colClasses = types) : colClasses[[1]][1] is NA**

Comment: `NAs introduced by coercion` suggest that there is something that doesn't look like that "time" in the column. Perhaps you missed `delim=","`? I suggest you find what that is, perhaps two calls, first *without* `col_types`: `orig <- vroom::vroom("..csv",delim=",")$Video.Time; parsed <- vroom::vroom("..csv",delim=",",col_types=types)$Video.Time; head(orig[is.na(VideoTime)]);` should show the first six unparsed values where it produced `NA`.

Comment: FYI, the `readr` package also uses this `col_time` premise, if you're more comfortable/familiar with it (though it's the same people).